# Environment variabile in Macro path

Tags: c

I need to define some path to files with macros. How can I use the $HOME environment variable?
I can't find it on the GNU manual, and this doesn't work:

```
#define LOGMMBOXMAN    "$HOME/mmbox/LOGmmboxman"
```

Comment: Don't use macros where macros aren't the correct tool.

Comment: then what should I use to define a path based on that env variable in my sources? without defining it several times along the sources themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are really asking "how can I set some cpp macro from my environment?"

If sothen you should just be able to add it to **CPPFLAGS**.

```
export CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -D LOGMMBOXMAN=$HOME/mmbox/LOGmmboxman"
```

Then in your code

```
#ifndef LOGBOXMAN
#error LOGBOXMAN not defined
#endif
```

Then make sure your source is built using the CPPFLAGS in the command line to gcc:

```
$ gcc -c file.c $CPPFLAGS
```

Comment: Thanks Ian! But I still can't get this work: my makefile exits with status="1". What am I missing?  Here the important statements:  CC = gcc
OPTIMIZE   = -g -Wall
CPPFLAGS   ="-D LOGMMBOXMAN=$HOME/mmbox/LOGmmboxman"
make: 
 gcc $(OPTIMIZE) $(CPPFLAGS) -o mmboxd mmboxd.c  
 gcc $(OPTIMIZE) $(CPPFLAGS) -o mmboxman mmboxman.c

Comment: Now I can compile, but the problem is this line: CPPFLAGS = "-D LOGMMBOXMAN='$(HOME)/mmbox/LOGmmboxman'".  The macro is not initialized as it should be, I guess problems with qoutes and slashes. When I try to print the macro value within a main example it throws out a segmentation fault, with this warning about the printf used: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’. Why does it assign a integer?

Comment: SOLVED: CPPFLAGS   = '-D LOGMMBOXMAN="$(HOME)/.mmbox/LOGmmboxman"'

Answer (score 5):

No it shouldn't and you probably don't want constant-defined settings like that in any case. If you did that and it worked as you're intending to use it, your home directory would be built in as whatever `$HOME` is for whoever's doing the building. The executable then depends on that specific home directory existing. If that's OK, just `#define` your own home. I suspect it isn't though, so you need to deduce it at runtime.

For run-time deduction what you want is [this](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html), such that:

```
const char* home_dir = getenv("HOME");
```

If there is no `$HOME` defined, you get `NULL` returned so be sure to test for this.

You can then build your string based on that. You'll need `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Note also that if `main` is declared as `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)` (allowed on Linux, OS X and Windows) then `envp` can also be used to access environment variables like `$HOME`.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons for wanting this kind of thing (perhaps not clear in the question) for instance, this is exactly how much of autotools works.

Comment: @Ian Yes, true, as I said in a comment to @Chris's answer. And as I said in mine, *if* you are OK with the fact you'll have a fixed home directory then you might as well just `#define` it as pass it in from the build system for all the benefit you'll get. It could be the OP was using `HOME` as an example and intends to pass in other variables, like say `PREFIX` as per autotools. But even applications like `postgres` that run as their own user cannot rely on me not changing `/etc/passwd` and moving that home.

Comment: In fact, I can think of an example where assumptions like this are bad. On windows, for example,  `%SystemRoot%` you'd expect to point at `C:\WINDOWS`. However, it really doesn't have to. So given a choice between "just use -D" and "dynamically construct your strings" I decided the latter was good advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You need to use your build system to define a macro with the `$HOME` value (or equivalent on a non-unix system), i.e. something like this:

```
gcc -DHOME="/home/username" file.c
```

Or `"/Users/username"` for Mac OS X, or `"C:\Users\username"` (or something) for Windows. Basically, GCC provides the `-D` flag to define a macro on the command line. You can set up a script (or your build system) to take care of this macro definition for you, or perhaps make a system-dependent include file to define the `HOME` macro properly.

Then, in your C header, you can do:

```
#define LOGMMBOXMAN HOME "/mmbox/LOGmmboxman"
```

Note that, in C, consecutive string literals are concatenated. So this macro expands to:

```
"/home/username" "/mmbox/LOGmmboxman"
```

Which C interprets as

```
"/home/username/mmbox/LOGmmboxman"
```

EDIT: All that thinking, and I didn't think! D'oh!

As others have pointed out, you probably don't want to do this. This will hard-code your program to work for one specific user's home directory. This will likely cause problems if you want each user to use your program, but for each to keep his (or her) own separate files.

[Ninefingers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690060/c-environment-variabile-in-macro-path/5690108#5690108) is what you're most likely looking for. In the event that you ever find yourself in need of the above technique (i.e. storing application files in a system-specific place) I will leave my answer unchanged, but I expect it won't help you here.

Comment: For a home path it might not be so useful to hardcode paths but most modern Unixes (Unices? Unicorns?) you'd expect say `/usr/bin` to exist, for example, so in that case a defined value is (probably, assuming you check existence/opening errors etc) fine and this technique gives you a good way to change those prefixes (e.g. to `/usr/local/bin`). So it does have a use.

Comment: I can't get this to work within my makefile (I'd like to append this macro: #define HOME /home/frfrf  so I'm trying with                gcc -D HOME=$HOME libglobal.h

Comment: @hysoka44 - I think you should use @Ninefingers' solution. If you use my solution, each user who wants to use your program would have to install it separately. It would be much easier for the program to dynamically look up who is using it, and store user-specific files in that user's home directory.

Comment: I understand what Nine said and I understood the problem you're gentle trying to have me avoid, but the small program I'm making is for a school project. In this, the program has to be installed and dependent from the home of the user, who is the pseudo-root in this micro system! Hope you get it: the solution chris posted sounds perfect for it! But I still can't define a macro within the commandline and I don't know what I'm missing. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @hysoka44 - Ah! Okay. The problem with `-D HOME=$HOME` is that the shell expands this to `-D HOME=/home/username`. You need quotes around the path: `-D HOME="$HOME"`. If you're using this from within a Makefile, that may work, but if the shell does too much interpreting (it happens when I try to use it directly from the command line) you need to escape the quotes: `-D HOME=\"$HOME\"` so that the shell knows "Yes, I want those quotes there, don't second guess me." Then the macro will expand to `"/home/username" as you expect it to.